# How can I insert my array of Objects in a JSON?

Tags: json, swift, ios9, swifty-json

I've created an Array of Objects in Swift which has the following structure:

```
var myCart:[FoodItem] = []
```

var dump:

```
    ▿ 3 elements
  ▿ [0]: TablePinAdolfoTesting.FoodItem #0
    - id: 5
    - name: Taco
    - cant: 2
  ▿ [1]: TablePinAdolfoTesting.FoodItem #1
    - id: 6
    - name: Burrito
    - cant: 1
  ▿ [2]: TablePinAdolfoTesting.FoodItem #2
    - id: 4
    - name: Enchiladas
    - cant: 3
```

I used Alamofire to get said object from my API but now, after changing them a little bit, I want to insert it into a new JSON which I created like so:

```
var json: JSON =  ["idUser": idUser, "total_loyalty_points": totalLP, "total_price": totalPrice, "car": []]
```

printed json:

```
  {
      "total_price" : 50000,
      "car" : [ 
      ],
      "idUser" : 58,
      "total_loyalty_points" : 5000
    }
```

**I have 2 issues with this...**

1. for some reason "car" is being placed at the 2nd position even though I put it last during the JSON declaration.
2. The second issue is that I don't know how to place my Array of Objects within that JSON to obtain something like this:

   ```
       {"idUser": (int),
        "total_loyalty_points": (double),
        "total_price":(double),
        "car":[
         {
          "id": (string),
          "name": (string),
          "cant": (int)
         }
        ]
       }
   ```

Where "car" is an Array of Objects within that JSON. I would prefer to do this using SwiftyJSON if possible to maintain consistency but it is not a requirement.

One thing that I tried but does not work is the following

```
for object in cart.myCart{
                var name = [String: String]()
                name["id"] = object.id
                name["name"] = object.name
                json["car"] = JSON(name)
                json["car"]["cant"] = JSON(object.cant)
            }
```

The reason it does not work is that this will not create an array in Cart, it will just overwrite the JSON

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first problem there is no solution as Map or Dictionary doesn't maintain the order.

Second problem is because of you are assigning json["car"] to JSON which is a object not array of objects. Modified code is:

```
    var cars = [[String: String]]()
    for object in cart.myCart{
        var name = [String: String]()
        name["id"] = object.id
        name["name"] = object.name
        name["cant"] = object.cant
        cars.append(name)
    }
    json["car"] = JSON(cars)
```

Comment: that is pretty much it... the only thing I had to change is that because `name["cant"]` is an int, I changed  `[[String: String]]()` for `String: AnyObject]()` 

Thank you